# How to change CSS with ':hover'

Tags: html, css, display, mousehover

HTML code

```css
.navbar li {
  color: #B7B7B7;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 70px;
  padding: 22px 16px 18px;
}
.navbar #menumain ul {
  width: 120%;
}
.navbar ul ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <li id="menumain">
    Menu1main
    <ul>
      <a href="/">
        <li>Menu2</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

How to change **display:none** in `navbar ul ul` to **display:block** with **`:hover`**
How to change **display:none** in `navbar ul ul` to **display:block** with **`:hover`** ?

Comment: can you add your code to jsfiddle?

Comment: Li elements must be child of ul/ol, not div

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing what you're asking for is something like this:

```
.navbar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

But your code is not clear. You currently have `.navbar ul ul` in your selector, but you don't have two nested `ul`s anywhere in your markup.

Answer (score 2):

```
.navbar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

I guess you mean this

EDIT: @David Hedlund You were faster

Answer (score 0):

You may try writing the `:hover` with your *div* class.

```
.navbar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

According to your HTML code, you do not have 2 `ul` instead 1 `li` and 1 `ul`.
Ideally it should be `ul` first and then `li` in HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong man.
a>li is a bad practice.
you need to do li>a

```css
.navbar > li > ul { display: none; }
.navbar > li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <li id="menumain">
    Menu1main
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">item2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

Remember HTML W3C Validator
**Error: Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)**